# Object keeps accelerating as it falls

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am a noob to this but anyway. I am writing an app in which you must tap in order to get an object up but at some point no matter how fast you tap the object keeps going down. it's  like the gravity is getting stronger and stronger.

EDIT: I don't know what code samples to give because i don't know if any of it makes sense, but i will try:

this is how i created the object:

```
super=display.newImage("mine.png")
super:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
super.y=display.contentHeight+70
super.x=display.contentWidth/2.3
super.gravityscale=1
superIntro = transition.to(super,{time=2000, y=display.contentHeight/1.2, onComplete= supergo})
physics.addBody(super, "dynamic", {density=0, bounce=0, friction=0, radius=12})`
```

And this is a part of my script that i think it is relevant: `

```
function scrollCity(self,event)
    print("touch")
    if self.y > 930 then
        self.y = 0
    else
        self.y=self.y+scrollspeed*6
    end
end

function activateJets(self,event)

self.y=self.y-scrollspeed*6
print("run")
end

function touchScreen(event)
print("p")
if event.phase == "began" then

    if super.y<display.contentHeight/1.2+6 then
        super.y=display.contentHeight/1.2
        background1.enterFrame = scrollCity
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", background1)
        background2.enterFrame = scrollCity
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", background2)
    else

        super.enterFrame = activateJets
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", super)
    end

 end
if event.phase == "ended" then

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", super)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", background1)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", background2)

end
end
```

EDIT2: The gravity is set:

```
physics.setGravity( 0, 1.5 )
```

In the beginning a few taps are enough to keep it on the screen, but after a few seconds it is impossible to maintain and it just falls. I want it to go down with the same speed not to accelerate.

Comment: Hi Alexandru, you will need to give some code sample of what you are doing or else it will be very difficult to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it keeps accelerating is because gravity applies a constant force. Anything affected by gravity undergoes acceleration, not a fixed velocity.

### For constant speed motion

Cancel the effect of gravity by setting `gravityscale` to 0 or setting global gravity to 0 - whichever is more appropriate for you - then setting the velocity of `super` using `super:setLinearVelocity( xVelocity, yVelocity )`.

### For motion with acceleration

If you prefer an accelerating gravity then the approach you are using now is fine but you might consider `super:setLinearVelocity(0, 0)` when the tap occurs so that the object is falling from rest rather than continuing to fall quickly.